# C++ Access object within a vector using an iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a class called **TechReport** which has a helper class called **Comment**. Instances of the Comment class are stored within **std::vector m_comments**

```
#ifndef TECHREPORT_H
#define TECHREPORT_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Report.h"
#include "BadResponseException.h"

// Lets the compiler know that I will define later
class Comment;

class TechReport : public Report {
 public:
  TechReport(int aID, std::string author, std::string title,
             std::string textBody);

  virtual bool Search(std::string searchString) const;
  virtual void DisplayBody() const;
  virtual TechReport *CreateResponse(std::string author, 
                   std::string textBody, int nextID) throw(BadResponseException);

 private:
  int commentCount;
  std::vector<Comment> m_comments;

};

class Comment {
 public:
  std::string m_author;
  std::string m_textBody;

  Comment(std::string author = "", std::string textBody = "")
    : m_author(author), m_textBody(textBody) {}
};

#endif
```

The issue I'm having is within the **Search** method. Within Search I create an iterator which I use in a for-loop to go through the elements in the vector. Here's my for-loop:

```
// searchString is a string (duh)
vector<Comment>::iterator it;

for (it = m_comments.begin(); it != m_comments.end(); it++) {
  if (it->m_textBody == searchString) {
    cout << "Found it\n";
    return true;
  }
}
```

This code is generating the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘it = ((const TechReport*)this)-
>TechReport::m_comments.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = Comment, _Alloc = 
std::allocator<Comment>]()’
```

So I'm assuming the error stems from the initialization of my for-loop, but I don't understand why. Correct me if I'm wrong, but is the iterator **it** a **random access iterator** which has the same functionality of a pointer? So all that's happening is it is being set to point at the first element in m_comments. What am I missing here?

Comment: There's no nested class in your code. Also, creating vectors of incomplete types is *undefined behaviour*. But better post a minimal but complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @vsoftco It is forbidden, but it is unlikely you'll get a compiler error just from instantiating the template.

Comment: @juanchopanza, thanks, the issue is quite interesting and just found a quite old article about the history of it http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suspicion is you're calling it from const method, thus you have (const TechReport*)this, and
you're trying to assign const_iterator from begin() to usual iterator

Could you change it to const_iterator and see if it works?

```
vector<Comment>::const_iterator it;

....
```

Comment: How about that. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks!